# Is it safe to use Microsoft.Data.SqlClient with .Net MAUI

Tags: c#, sql, cross-platform

I'm working on a .net maui app that is intended to be a modern, lightweight alternative to SQL Management Studio. I thought this would be a good project to learn .NET Maui with, since I am already very familiar with SQL Server, doing database backups, restores, etc.

I started a .NET Maui app, and added the Microsoft.Data.SqlClient nuget package to my MAUI project, but I'm seeing a lot of warnings about the dependencies possibly not playing nice with MacCatalyst... However, so far everything seems to work. Is it safe to ignore the warnings, or are there deeper issues that I should expect to run into?

I tried googling, but there's not a lot of info about how sqlclient gets along in a MAUI environment. Any thoughts or suggestions are appreciated.

Examples of warnings I see:
`/Users/jjackson/code/sqlmanager/sqlmanager.csproj: Warning NU1703: 'Microsoft.CSharp 4.5.0' was resolved as a dependency of 'sqlmanager', but the dependency is using 'Xamarin.iOS' while 'sqlmanager' is using 'net6.0-maccatalyst15.4' as its TargetFramework. There might be compatibility issues when MacCatalyst projects depend on Xamarin.iOS projects. (NU1703) (sqlmanager)`

Comment: Not the point, but there's already a modern lightweight alternative to SSMS, called [Azure Data Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/azure-data-studio/?view=sql-server-ver16)

Comment: There may be more to it but I think the base of the problem is that you're using Xamarin dependencies with Maui. Not hard to do because Maui's still in preview (I think) and most of the examples you'll find are with Xamarin. Add to that, they're not a 1:1 port (in my xp). I would try to find Maui-compatible dependencies if possible or fly close to the sun until it's GA.